# Summation equation for $2^{x-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, geometric-progressions

Since everyone freaked out, I made the variables are the same.
$$
\sum_{x=1}^{n} 2^{x-1}
$$

I've been trying to find this for a while. I tried the usually geometric equation [(Here)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum) but I couldn't get it right (if you need me to post my work I will). Here's the outputs I need:

1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63

If my math is correct.

Comment: Don't you mean $$\sum_{i=1}^n 2^{i-1}$$?

Comment: That thing you have there sure ain't convergent...

Comment: You don't mean to sum just $n$ terms ?

Comment: Changed that $\infty$ to $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the equation for the sum of a geometric series:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a\cdot r^{i-1}=\frac{a(r^n-1)}{r-1}$$
where $a$ is the initial value of the sequence $u_n=a\cdot r^{n-1}$ and $r\ne1$. In your specific case the equation becomes:

$$\frac{1\cdot(2^n-1)}{2-1}=2^n-1$$
So the sum of the first $n$ terms is $2^n-1$

Answer (score 10):

In this instance, without explicitly using the formula for geometric series,
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{x=1}^n 2^{x-1} &= 1 + 2 + 2^2 + 2^3 + \cdots + 2^{n-1}\\
&= 1 + (1 + 2 + 2^2 + 2^3 + \cdots + 2^{n-1}) - 1 &\text{add and subtract}~ 1\\
&= (1 + 1) + (2 + 2^2 + 2^3 + \cdots + 2^{n-1}) - 1 &\text{regroup}\\
&= 2 + (2 + 2^2 + 2^3 + \cdots + 2^{n-1}) - 1\\
&= (2 + 2) + (2^2 + \cdots + 2^{n-1}) - 1 &\text{regroup again}\\
&= 2^2 + (2^2 + 2^3 + \cdots + 2^{n-1}) - 1\\
&= (2^2 + 2^2) + (2^3 + \cdots + 2^{n-1}) - 1 &\text{regroup again}\\
&= 2^3 + (2^3 + \cdots + 2^{n-1}) - 1\\
&= \cdots &\text{lather, rinse, repeat}\\
&= 2^{n-1} + (2^{n-1}) - 1 &\text{nearly done}\\
&= 2^n - 1.
\end{align*}$$
Now that we know the form of the result, it is also possible
to prove the result

> $$\sum_{x=1}^n 2^{x-1} = 2^n - 1$$

more formally by induction. Clearly, 
 the result holds when $n = 1$ since $2^0 = 2^1 - 1$.
Then, if the result holds for some positive integer $n$, we have
that

$$\sum_{x=1}^{n+1} 2^{x-1} = \sum_{x=1}^n 2^{x-1} + 2^n
= (2^n-1) + 2^n = 2^{n+1} - 1$$
and so the result holds for $n+1$ as well. Since we know
that the result holds when $n=1$, it follows by induction
that it holds for all positive integers $n$.

Comment: "$\rm lather, rinse, repeat$" +1

Answer (score 6):

You're saying you want as outputs

$1,3,7,15,31,63$

Note they are respectively $2^1-1,2^2-1,2^3-1,2^4-1,2^5-1,2^6-1$ so what you really want is $$f(n)=2^n-1$$

Now this is a **finite** geometric sum, namely

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2^i=2^n-1$$

This follows from the geometric sum formula, that is

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a^i=\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}$$

The MO for this is the following. Let our sum be $S$

$$1 + a +  \cdots  + {a^{n - 1}} = S$$

Then

$$a + {a^2} +  \cdots  + {a^n} = aS$$

But

$$a + {a^2} +  \cdots  + {a^n} = \left( {1 + a +  \cdots  + {a^{n - 1}}} \right) - 1 + {a^n} = S - 1 + {a^n}$$

So that

$$\eqalign{
  & S - 1 + {a^n} = aS  \cr 
  & S - aS = 1 - {a^n}  \cr 
  & \left( {1 - a} \right)S = 1 - {a^n}  \cr 
  & S = \frac{{1 - {a^n}}}{{1 - a}} \cr} $$

as desired.

Answer (score 2):

For sum upto $n$ terms $$\sum_{x=1}^n 2^{x-1}=\frac{\sum_{x=1}^n 2^x}{2}$$ Numerator is the usual geometric series $a,ar,ar^2,\cdots,ar^{n-1}$ which sum is $$\frac{a(r^n-1)}{r-1}$$ which gives $$\frac{\sum_{x=1}^n 2^x}{2}=\frac{2(2^n-1)}{2(2-1)}=2^n-1$$

Comment: Oh, oops, I did the equation wrong. It's supposed to be 2^(x-1)

Comment: Maybe you should edit your answer, or delete it entirely.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align*} \sum_{i=1}^{n} 2^{i-1} &= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^{i}\\
&=1+2+2^2 \cdots 2^{n-1} \\ &=\frac{2^{n}-1}{2-1} \quad \quad \text{(usual geometric series formula)} \\ &=2^n -1
 \end{align*} \\ $$

Comment: Why are you keeping the $x$ in the summands?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff oh that was a mistake.Now I have corrected.

Answer (score 0):

A very short 'proof':$$\begin{align}2\sum_{x=1}^n2^{x-1}&=2^n+2^{n-1}+\dots+4+2\\-\left(\quad\sum_{x=1}^n2^{x-1}\right.&=\left.\phantom{2^n}\quad\ 2^{n-1}+\dots+4+2+1\vphantom{\sum_{x=1}^n2^{x-1}}\right)\\\hline\sum_{x=1}^n2^{x-1}&=2^n-1\tag{subtract the two}\end{align}$$

Comment: You might want to check your last line for typos.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Haha, it was somewhat elegant up until that XD

Comment: Yes, but note also that your very short proof is just a special case of the last part of Pedro Tamaroff's answer where he _derives_ the sum of geometric series formula that most of the other answers take for granted.

Comment: That doesn't mean my answer is any less right or intuitive.  If I may, my answer is much more suited as a three-line proof of Pedro's entire answer, just change a few numbers around.  The point of my answer is to be visual, not rigorous or anything like that.

Comment: Yes, but your answer adds nothing new to what has already been said before in four other answers. It merely bumps up the question to the top of the page.

Comment: @DilipSarwate It may not to you or I, but to someone who asked this question or who came here not knowing the answer, my answer may very well be more understandable to them.  Quality is not always about content.