# How can I demonstrate that the decimal equivalent for a binary number consisting of $n$ $1$'s is $2^n-1$?

Tags: number-systems

I know that $2^n-1$ gives you the decimal equivalent for any word consisting of $n$ $1$'s, but how can I demonstrate that in general terms for any word of $n$ $1$'s?

Comment: It's nozt the decimal equivalent, it's simply the number

Comment: Related [answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188851/calculating-the-chess-problem-sum-sum-k-0632k).

Answer (score 1):

Sum the implicit geometric series:

$$\underbrace{111\ldots111}_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^k=\;?$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** what is the result if you add $1$ to any such word? What does that tell you?