# How to prove by induction that $\sum^n_{i=1}2^{i-1}=2^n-1$?

Tags: induction, summation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I prove this by induction? (sum of powers of 2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22599/how-do-i-prove-this-by-induction-sum-of-powers-of-2)
>   [Summation equation for $2^{x-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180169/summation-equation-for-2x-1)

How can I prove the following by induction?
$$
\sum^n_{i=1}2^{i-1}=2^n-1
$$
I get to 
$$
\ldots+2^{i-1}=2^n-1+2^{i-1}
$$
and don't see what the next step is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $n=1$, we see

$$2-1=2^0$$

so LHS=RHS.  Assuming that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n 2^{i-1}=2^n-1$$

we have, changing $n$ to $n+1$, the inductive step:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} 2^{i-1} = 2^n+\sum_{i=1}^{n} 2^{i-1}=2^n+2^{n}-1=2^{n+1}-1$$

so LHS=RHS.

QED

Comment: I'm not following you at the inductive step. Shouldn't it be $\sum^{n+1}_{i=1}2^{i-1}=2^n-1+\sum^n_{i=1}2^{i-1}$?

Comment: @mirai, the term $2^n$ results from evaluating the summand at $i=n+1$ and separating it from the summation notation. In other words, $2^{i-1}=2^{n+1-1}=2^{n}$. Hence, $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}2^{i-1}=2^n+\sum_{i=1}^{n}2^{i-1}.$$

Comment: @Limitless That makes sense, thanks.

Comment: @mirai, You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You start with the inductive hypothesis
$$\sum_{i=1}^n2^{i-1} = 2^n - 1$$
for some $n$. Now for $n+1$ you have
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}2^{i-1} = 2^n + \sum_{i=1}^n2^{i-1}$$
Can you see how to finish it off?

Answer (score 0):

(Warning: Puckishness ahead!)
When you do induction on a sum $\sum_{k=a}^b x_k$, you either decapitate like so
$$\sum_{k=a}^b x_k = x_b + \sum_{k=a}^{b-1} x_k,$$
or you exungulate (trim toenails) like so
$$\sum_{k=a}^b x_k = x_a + \sum_{k=a+1}^b x_k.$$
This will convey you to the induction step neatly.

Comment: Sometimes you might want to lop off a couple of terms....