# Proof By Induction Help?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction

I've been working through proof by induction and i'm stuck on this question. Can somebody provide some help?
$$ 2^n-1=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2^i\text{ for }n\ge 1$$

Comment: Which step in the induction process are you stuck on? What have you attempted so far? What is your understanding of induction?

Comment: If you learn some [telescopy](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+telescopy) such inductive proofs become very trivial.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761156/proof-by-induction-that-sum-j-0n-2j-2n1-1
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209518/how-to-prove-by-induction-that-sumn-i-12i-1-2n-1
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22599/how-do-i-prove-this-by-induction-sum-of-powers-of-2
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180169/summation-equation-for-2x-1 ... and many other question you can find on this site. (For example, looked at related and linked questions at those question I've mentioned here.)

Answer (score 2):

First, show that this is true for $n=1$:

- $2^1-1=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{1-1}2^i$

Second, assume that this is true for $n$:

- $2^n-1=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}2^i$

Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:

- $2^{n+1}-1=2\cdot2^n-1$
- $2\cdot2^n-1=2\cdot2^n-2+1$
- $2\cdot2^n-2+1=2\cdot(2^n-1)+1$
- $2\cdot(2^n-1)+1=1+2\cdot(2^n-1)$
- $1+2\cdot(2^n-1)=1+2\cdot\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}2^i$ `assumption used here`
- $1+2\cdot\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}2^i=1+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}2^i$
- $1+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}2^i=2^0+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}2^i$
- $2^0+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}2^i=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}2^i$

Comment: thank you i've got it - but can i just ask how you got to the third part bullet point 1? - how did you get to 2(2n - 1)

Comment: @Mathematica: Which bullet do you mean, the first one in the third part?

Comment: @Mathematica: I just tried to represent the proof subject ($2^{n+1}-1$) using the assumption subject ($2^{n}-1$). The ratio between them is approximately $2$, right? So I multiplied the assumption subject by $2$, and then added what was necessary in order to make them equal (i.e., $+1$).

Comment: @Mathematica: I've slightly expanded it in order to make it easier for you to understand.

Comment: @Mathematica: I've significantly expanded it in order to make it easier for you to understand.

Comment: thank you so much for the help - I'm struggling to understand one thing - how did you get [2 * ] (2n -1) on the first line?

Comment: @Mathematica: You're welcome. Are you struggling to understand $2^{n+1}=2\cdot2^n$???

Comment: yes i don't understand how you got the 2 *

Comment: @Mathematica: Let me get this right - you don't understand **that**, but you understand **all the rest**???

Comment: Yeah - I've understood the basic concept of whats going on but i want to confirm how you got that

Comment: @Mathematica: Do you understand what $2^n$ means?

Comment: yes I understand that - are you just using the indices rule?

Comment: @Mathematica: Then surely you understand what happens when you multiply it by $2$... right?

Comment: @barakmanos oh my god, this is the funniest comment section ever. I laughed so hard when you were shocked by him not understanding $2^{n+1} = (2)(2^n)$

Comment: @elbarto: I did do my best trying to explain it though, didn't I?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** : $2^{n+1}-1=2(2^n-1)+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Guest has given a very good hint. Alternatively, you can generalize:

For any $x,y \in \Bbb{R}$ then $$x^n-y^n = (x-y)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}y^ix^{n-1-i}$$ If you prove this by induction, then your proof follows as a special case of $x=2, y=1$. Your original proof is probably easier than this one, but this one is a good result to have regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Although the hint by Guest is quite good, as graydad pointed out, I imagine you are probably struggling with some summation manipulation (or am I wrong?). Here's a brief sketch (I imagine you can fill in all of the fine details and make the argument flow like a written proof should):
\begin{align}
2^{k+1}-1 &= 2\cdot(2^k-1)+1\\[1em]
          &= 2\cdot\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}2^i + 1\\[1em]
          &= \sum_{i=1}^k2^i + 1\\[1em]
          &= \sum_{i=0}^k2^i.
\end{align}
Does that make more sense now?