# Proof by Induction $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 2^i = 2^k-1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, induction

Prove mathematical induction $$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 2^i = 2^k-1$$

Comment: A proof can be found towards the end of  [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/180255/15941).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean  $2^k-1$ then

base case $k=1$ then

$$\sum_{i=0}^{1-1}2^i = 1 = 2^1 -1$$

Now 
$$\begin{align}\sum_{i=0}^{k}2^i & = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}2^i +2^k \\[0.5ex] & = 2^k -1 + 2^k & \textsf{assuming }\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} = 2^k-1 \\[0.5ex] & = 2^12^k-1 \\[0.5ex] & =2^{k+1}-1 \end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot :D