# What is the result of sum $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n 2^i$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, geometric-progressions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [the sum of powers of $2$ between $2^0$ and $2^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86838/the-sum-of-powers-of-2-between-20-and-2n)

What is the result of 
$$2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + \cdots + 2^{n-1} + 2^n\ ?$$

Is there a formula on this? and how to prove the formula?

(It is actually to compute the time complexity of a Fibonacci recursive method.)

Comment: Yes, there is a formula. Consider what the result looks like in binary notation. What happens if you add 1 to the result (still in binary)?

Comment: You know how a geometric series works?

Comment: $2^{n+1}-1$ is correct. If you need to produce a rigorous proof, I suggest induction.

Comment: @null Isn't the time complexity of a Fibonacci recursive method given in terms of the Fibonacci numbers?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: Nice catch, I was trying to find it but didn't know what exactly I want to find!

Comment: @Gigili ?? You were trying to find what? A duplicate?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: Yes? What's wrong with it? I had a strong sense of deja vu that we had the question before.

Comment: @talmid I just have a class for time complexity, then I looked at past-year exam paper, there is a question about complexity of Fibonacci recursion, so I was trying to figure out the time complexity of that.thanks so much !

Comment: @Gigili : I was just confused with your "Nice catch", I didn't understand if it meant you liked the fact that I found a duplicate, or the content of my answer there, something like that.

Comment: @null See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360748/computational-complexity-of-fibonacci-sequence. You don't need to compute sums of powers of $2$.

Comment: I am extremely amused as to why you didn't vote to close yourself @PatrickDaSilva!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let $S = 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + \cdots + 2^{n}$.

Then $2S = 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 + \cdots + 2^{n} + 2^{n+1}$.

Then
$$\begin{align*}
S = 2S - S &=     & & 2^1 &+& 2^2 & + & 2^3 & + & 2^4 &+&\cdots &+& 2^{n} &+& 2^{n+1}\\
&& -2^0 -& 2^1 & - & 2^2 & - & 2^3 & - & 2^4 & - & \cdots & - & 2^n
\end{align*}$$
How much is that?

Comment: It's at least +1!

Answer (score 12):

Might be overkill, but there is a well known identity for sums of the form $\sum_{i=0}^n x^i$ where $x$ is not 1.

$$\sum_{i = 0}^n x^i = \frac{1- x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$

Now plug in 2 and you have what you seek.

This identity can easily be proven by induction.

Comment: I wouldn't call this "overkill", but rather "standard approach". The proof of this identity is essentially the standard approach when one tries to prove this identity for $x = 2$.

Comment: This is usually an standard exercise in your first `proof' course at the university.

Answer (score 8):

I thought I might post a little more elaborate version of Henning's hint (see his [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158758/what-is-the-result-of-sum-sum-limits-i-0n-2i#comment366057_158758)).
$$\begin{align}
  1&=2^0\\
 10&=2^1\\
100&=2^2\\
1000&=2^3\\
\vdots&=\vdots\\
10\dots0&=2^n\\
\hline
11\dots1&=2^0+2^1+\dots+2^n\\
        1&=1\\
\hline
100\dots0&=2^0+2^1+\dots+2^n+1=2^{n+1}
\end{align}$$
Hence $2^0+2^1+\dots+2^n=2^{n+1}-1$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Consider the sequence of partial sums $(a_n) = 2^0 + \cdots + 2^n$. Add one to each term. Do you notice a pattern?

For example:

$a_0 + 1 = 2^0 + 1 = \dots$

$a_1 + 1 = 2^0 + 2^1 + 1 = \dots$

$a_2 + 1 = 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + 1 = \dots$

Can you guess what a general formula for $a_n + 1$ might be? Then what is $a_n$?
An easy way to prove this would be by induction.

Since you already know $a_n = 2^{n+1} - 1$, the proof by induction goes like this:

- Base case: with $n=0$: $a_0 = 2^0 = 1$, which is $2^{0+1}-1$, so the formula holds for the base case.
- Inductive step: if $a_n = 2^{n+1}-1$, then $a_{n+1} = a_n + 2^{n+1}$ (because to get to the next term in the sequence you just add the next power of $2$); by the inductive hypothesis, this is equal to $(2^{n+1}-1) + 2^{n+1} = 2 \times 2^{n+1} - 1 = 2^{(n+1)+1} - 1$, which is the formula we conjectured for $a_{n+1}$.

With this, we've shown $a_n = 2^{n+1}-1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$.

Answer (score 4):

How much is a direct summation worth?
$$\begin{align*}
1 + \sum_{i=0}^n 2^i &= 1 + (2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + \cdots + 2^n)\\
&= (2^0 + 2^0) + (2^1 + 2^2 + \cdots + 2^n)\\
&= 2^1 + (2^1 + 2^2 + \cdots + 2^n)\\
&= (2^1 + 2^1) + (2^2 + \cdots + 2^n)\\
&= 2^2 + (2^2 + \cdots + 2^n)\\
\vdots &= \ddots\\
&= 2^n + (2^n)\\
&= 2^{n+1}.
\end{align*}$$
Hence, $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^n 2^i = 2^{n+1} - 1.$

Comment: It's at least worth +1!

Answer (score 3):

Let us take a particular example that is large enough to illustrate the general situation. Concrete experience should precede the abstract.

Let $n=8$. We want to show that $2^0+2^1+2^2+\cdots +2^8=2^9-1$.  We could add up on a calculator, and verify that the result holds for $n=8$. However, we would not learn much during the process.

We will instead look at the sum written backwards, so at
$$2^8+2^7+2^6+2^5+2^4+2^3+2^2+2^1+2^0.$$
A kangaroo is $2^9$ feet from her beloved $B$. She takes a giant leap of $2^8$ feet. Now she is $2^8$ feet from $B$.  She takes a leap of $2^7$ feet. Now she is $2^7$ feet from $B$. She takes a leap of $2^6$ feet. And so on. After a while she is $2^1$ feet from $B$, and takes a leap of $2^0$ feet, leaving her $2^0$ feet from $B$.

The total distance she has covered is $2^8+2^7+2^6+\cdots+2^0$.  It leaves her $2^0$ feet from $B$, and therefore 
$$2^8+2^7+2^6+\cdots+2^0+2^0=2^9.$$
Since $2^0=1$, we obtain by subtraction that $2^8+2^7+\cdots +2^0=2^9-1$.

We can write out the same reasoning without the kangaroo.  Note that 
$2^0+2^0=2^1$, $2^1+2^1=2^2$, $2^2+2^2=2^3$, and so on until $2^8+2^8=2^9$.
Therefore
$$(2^0+2^0)+2^1+2^2+2^3+2^4+\cdots +2^8=2^9.$$
Subtract the front $2^0$ from the left side, and $2^0$, which is $1$, from the right side, and we get our result.

Comment: I mean, seriously? A kangaroo? Gosh. $2^8$ feet leaps? Man... +1 for the laugh

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: Yes, seriously. Someone reading it with attention may be able to reconstruct the idea a year from now.

Comment: @AndréNicolas "A Hulk is $2^9$ feet from her beloved..." would be more interesting. +1

Comment: @AndreNicolas : You seem to like this pedagogic approach a lot. I respect you for that =) sometimes people forget that you need to do mathematics to have fun! When there's no fun, there's no theorem.

Answer (score 0):

This is called as a Geometric progression. YES there is a formula.
Refer this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression

The answer for your problem is 2^(n-1).

You want the proof refer the above link. Simple and excellent

Comment: Its 2^(n+1)....my bad.

Comment: Note that the sum has exactly one odd number and therefore the sum cannot be an odd number. So your answers $2^{n-1},2^{n+1}$ are wrong.